# Unreachable Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a running amazon-ec2 instance that contains a personal wiki. It has been running fine for years, and today suddenly I'm unable to logon using the private key .ppk file using either Putty or WinSCP! (An hour ago I still can!)

I was panicking and I rebooted the amazon EC2 instance. (I didn't stop and start the instance, I choose reboot).

My question is, is my data lost? And if not, how can I recover it? I can't ssh to the machine and it seems my .pem file or .ppk file which I generated long time back doesn't work anymore.

Your help is much appreciated, it saves me a lot of hard work! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try starting another ec2 instance, and attaching the EBS volume(of the instance you care about) to it. Then all you have to do is to mount it and your data should be intact.

You'll have to turn off the original instance to do that first. Also, this presumes you don't have the drive encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your data will be lost only if you used instance store. If you used EBS, your data is intact.
2. If you can't SSH to your server, use "AWS Systems Manager" to shell into your instance and debug SSH connection: check if sshd is up, `.ssh/authorized_keys` file contents and permissions, etc...